# How to edit rows in a data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose, I have a data frame `d` like this

```
  > d
   x Y
r1 1 1
r2 1 2
r3 1 3
r4 1 4
r5 1 5
r6 1 6
```

I want to divide rows `r3,r4` by 5 and get the whole data frame with edited rows

```
   x   Y
r1 1.0 1.0
r2 1.0 2.0
r3 0.2 0.6
r4 0.2 0.8
r5 1.0 5.0
r6 1.0 6.0
```

I know I can do this by

```
p1 <- d[1:2, ]
p2 <- d[c("r3", "r4"), ]/5
p3 <- d[5:6, ]
rbind(p1, p2, p3)
```

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: just use this: `d[c("r3", "r4"), ] <-d[c("r3", "r4"), ]/5`

Comment: Thank you! @Dave2e